# Use IRET into CPL=3 in long mode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, interrupt, osdev, interrupt-handling

I am creating a handwritten OS and have some problems with the interrupt handling.
The problem is that when I try to return to CPL=3 from an interrupt, I get a general protection fault.
I looked up in the intel manual, and my conclusion is that in long mode, one can not return into a different code segment with iret.
So i came up with a solution that it uses sysret to return into a CPL=3 code which then jumps to the usercode. It seems to be working, but there is a little issue. Sometimes an interrupt comes in the middle of the CPL=3 code.
I can not enable interrupts at the end of the CPL=3 code, becuause it is only possible in CPL=0.

Is there anything I missed about the iret instrucion?
Or do I use some black magic like a far return?

**This code works, but after a while it breaks, because an interrupt comes when it is in the CPL3 part.**

My code looks like this: (NASM syntax)

```
    ; Registers are restored and neccessary values are pushed onto the stack
    mov rax, cpu_cs ; check if return is to cpl0
    mov rax, [rax]
    cmp rax, 0x8 ; 0x8 is the kernel segment
    jne iretq_cpl3
    
    ; return to cpl0
    mov rax, cpu_rax ; restore rax
    mov rax, [rax]

    iretq

iretq_cpl3: ;return to cpl3
    mov rax, cpu_rax ; restore rax from current_state
    push qword [rax]

    mov rax, cpl3_rax ; save rax to cpl_rax
    pop qword [rax]

    mov rax, cpl3_rcx ; save rcx
    mov [rax], rcx

    add rax, 8 ; save r11
    mov [rax], r11

    add rax, 8 ; pop and save rip
    pop qword [rax]

    add rsp, 8 ; dispose cs

    pop r11 ; rflags into r11 for sysret; save it for cpl3 code
    
    pop rsp ; restore rsp

    mov rcx, cpl3_returner ; go to cpl3_returner

    o64 sysret
```

And the CPL=3 code:

```
; cpl3
align(4096)

global cpl3_kernel_part
global cpl3_reg_save
global cpl3_returner
cpl3_kernel_part:
cpl3_reg_save:
    cpl3_rax: dq 0
    cpl3_rcx: dq 0
    cpl3_r11: dq 0
    cpl3_rip: dq 0
cpl3_returner:
    mov rax, cpl3_r11 ; restore r11
    mov r11, [rax]

    mov rax, cpl3_rcx ; restore rcx
    mov rcx, [rax]

    mov rax, cpl3_rip ; push rip on the stack for the return
    push qword [rax]

    mov rax, cpl3_rax ; restore rax
    mov rax, [rax]

    ret
```

EDIT:

**This is the error code if I try to use IRETQ, so basicly when I use the cpl3 code with cpl3 too.**

The exception I get when I try to return to CPL3 with IRETQ:

```
!!! Exception: 0xD //#GP
Error code: 0x28 //User code segment
SS: 0x10 //Kernel stack segment
CS: 0x8 //Kernel code segment
RSP: 0x20000024F98
RAX: 0x0
RIP: 0x200000031DA
instr: 0x48 0xCF 0x48 0xB8 0x60 0x37 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0xC6 0x0 0x0 //IRETQ
!!!
```

The stack just before IRETQ:

```
(gdb) x/5gx 0x20000024f98 //rsp
0x20000024f98:  0x0000000000000000 // User RIP    0x000000000000002b // User CS is 0x28
0x20000024fa8:  0x0000000000000202 // RFLAGS      0x0000000000006fec // User RSP
0x20000024fb8:  0x0000000000000023 // User SS is 0x20
```

The RIP is 0x0 on purpose. The user code is just `jmp $`, and it is mapped to the first page.

The GDT looks like this:

```c
__attribute__((aligned(4096)))
struct {
  struct gdt_entry null;
  struct gdt_entry kernel_code;
  struct gdt_entry kernel_data;
  struct gdt_entry null2;
  struct gdt_entry user_data;
  struct gdt_entry user_code;
  struct gdt_entry ovmf_data;
  struct gdt_entry ovmf_code;
  struct gdt_entry tss_low;
  struct gdt_entry tss_high;
} gdt_table = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, 0},  /* 0x00 null  */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0},  /* 0x08 kernel code (kernel base selector) */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x92, 0xa0, 0},  /* 0x10 kernel data */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, 0},  /* 0x18 null (user base selector) */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x92, 0xa0, 0},  /* 0x20 user data */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0},  /* 0x28 user code */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x92, 0xa0, 0},  /* 0x30 ovmf data */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x9a, 0xa0, 0},  /* 0x38 ovmf code */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x89, 0xa0, 0},  /* 0x40 tss low */
    {0, 0, 0, 0x00, 0x00, 0},  /* 0x48 tss high */

};
```

It is from [this](https://blog.llandsmeer.com/tech/2019/07/21/uefi-x64-userland.html) website.

I got it to be a bit more stable, by adding a flag, that if it is not set, the interrupt is immediately returned.
The cpl3 code sets it just before the return, but it is still not a perfect solution.

I noticed an interesting thing though. If I run it simply in qemu, it crashes after a few seconds, but if I attach GDB, it runs for minutes.

Here is my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Laci0503/LaciOS2/).

Comment: Of course you can return to user-mode code using IRETQ. You just need to make sure that the registers and stack contents are the  same as when the interrupt entered the kernel. Can you point to the part in the manual that made you think otherwise?

Comment: The manual says in the 64-bit exception part, that a #GP(Selector) may occur, ```If the DPL for a nonconforming-code segment is not equal to the RPL of the code segment selector.```. So I may have confused myself a bit with this sentence. At first I thought that this means that the privilege level of the current CS must match the descriptor I want to return to. And it was a perfect coincidence, because I only got the #GP if I was returning to CPL=3. I will provide more information about the code, and the stack. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Isn't your `iretq_cpl3` eventually using `sysret`, not `iret`?  The debugger dump does show 48 CF iretq, though.

Comment: It uses sysret, I want to find out how to use iret instead.

Comment: Can you show your GDT?  Was the user code running before, or is this the first entry into user code? Why is user rsp not aligned? (That wouldn’t cause #GP, though.)

Comment: I will add an edit with the most detailed information I can give.

Comment: Problems in the GDT: 1) For data segments, L is reserved. 2) User mode segments should have DPL = 3.

Comment: 3) I’ve always set D/B to 1 in 64-bit data segments; I don’t know if it matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I fixed my GDT and it works flowlessly. I don't know how it worked with sysret, but it now works with iret too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be my gdt that was faulty. Thanks for your help.